# дочерная форма не польностью помещается в клиентскую часть главной формы

Tags: delphi

У меня 2 проблемы:
1. Хочу иметь дочерные формы которые при открытии полностью поместится в клиентскую область главной формы. Не могу установыть высоту дочерней формы Form1 чтобы она и компоненты,например, DBGrid,полностью поместились на экран.
2. чтобы дочерные формы имели **кнопки в своем заголовк**е а не в mainmenu. 
На форме есть TabSet и ToolBar. 
В OnCreate дочерней формы пишу:

```
Form1.Height:=
MainForm.ClientHeight-MainForm.MDIChildrenTabs.Height-MainForm.ToolBar1.Height;
```

на доч. форме расположены 2 кнопки:

```
button1.Caption:=inttostr(Form1.Height); 
button2.Caption:=inttostr(MainForm.ClientHeight);
```

с их помощью узнаю, что Form1.height=805, MainForm.ClientHeight=956 но все равно не видна нижная часть формы и появляются полосы прокрутки(см. рисунок).

для главной

```
 Formstyle=MDIForm, 
 Windowstate=maximized
```

а для дочерней-

```
Formstyle=MDIChild,
Windowstate=Normal
```

Как помочь?

**Project:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzX341-bH8y5WDV5RC1RTHdRQVk/view?usp=sharing

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: статус бар еще внизу?

Comment: @teran На главной форме есть statusbar.

Comment: да я вижу, его то тоже вычесть надо. вряд ли правда это поможет )

Comment: @teran statusbar.height=16. я вычел даже 100 но не помогает.

Comment: Возьмите за правило не полагаться на четкие размеры. Лучше используйте "резиновость" - Anchors / Align.

Comment: @Kromster Align=acClient, Anchors-[akLeft, akTop, akRight] или [akLeft, akTop, akTop, akRight] но никакой разницы.

Comment: В теме добавил линк на проект

Comment: @Delphi159 `Form1.Align=alNone;` меняйте размер в Form1.OnShow, и если не ошибаюсь, то еще надо отнимать толщину рамки, я так сделал `Form1.Height:=
MainForm.ClientHeight-MainForm.MDIChildrenTabs.Height-MainForm.ToolBar1.Height-4;`

Comment: @Artgrek13  -4 не хватает, пишу так: 
Form1.Align=alNone;
Form1.Height:=MainForm.ClientHeight-MainForm.MDIChildrenTabs.Height-MainForm.ToolBar1.Height-25;
  Form1.Width:=MainForm.ClientWidth-25; но, во первых, форма не прилипается к TabSet  и свободно плавает на экран. Во вторых, как менять размеры формы для  других размеров экрана?

Comment: @Delphi159 "как менять размеры формы для других размеров экрана?" поместить этот код в Form1.OnPaint или MainForm.OnResize

Comment: @Delphi159  что значит "форма не прилипается к TabSet"? Она должна запуститься прямо под TabSet, а что б не плавала запускайте в Windowstate=maximized

Comment: @ArtGrek13  Если запускать в Windowstate=maximized тогда BordersIcons поднимается на mainmenu из заголовка дочерней формы, а если  Windowstate=Normal тогда появляются скроллбары . 
А я хочу: иметь дочерные формы которые при открытии полностью поместится в клиентскую область главной формы и чтобы дочерные формы имели кнопки в своем заголовке а не в mainmenu.  
см. проект если не трудно.

Comment: Может больше подойдет PageControl? Вместо форм

Comment: хах, я тут проект изучал, а оказывается в комментах уже нашли причину косяка.

Answer (score 1):

в общем, два нюанса.

1. У вас в проекте у дочернего окна выставлено `align = alClient`. Это и не дает изменить размеры окна. Измените на `alNone` и сможете задавать значение.
2. Когда измените п.1 вертикальный скролл все равно будет появляться. По какой то причине необходимо еще вычесть ширину рамки окна.

---

```
Form1.Height := MainForm.ClientHeight - MainForm.MDIChildrenTabs.Height 
                - MainForm.ToolBar1.Height
                - MainForm.statusbar.Height
                - 2*GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE);
```

При использовании VCL-стилей, наверное, потребуется получать значение ширины рамки через `TStyleManager`, или как его там.

зы: не используйте внутри собственной формы (`TForm1`) глобальные переменные вида `form1`, пишите либо просто `Height :=`, либо `self.Height :=`. Глобальные переменные для форм вообще зло, избегайте их.

Этот код, для вычисления высоты, следует вынести в класс главной формы, а значение получать через свойство. Дочерняя форма в принципе не должна знать об устройстве главной, и что там  из чего следует вычитать. Добавьте в главную форму

```
public 
  property MDIClientHeight : integer read getMDIClientHeight;
```

и соответствующий метод:

```
function TMainForm.getMDIClientHeight():integer;
begin
    result := ClientHeight - ....;  
end;
```

Comment: teran  1) Если  align = alNone тогда форма не прилипается к TabSet  и свободно "плавает" на экран при перетаскивании маусом. 
2) Form1.Height := MainForm.ClientHeight - MainForm.MDIChildrenTabs.Height - MainForm.ToolBar1.Height
                - MainForm.statusbar.Height не дал никакого результата. 
                - 2*GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE);

Comment: @Delphi159 если вы хотите жестко закрепить дочернее окно в главной форме, то MDI это вообще не то что вам надо. У него идея другая совсем. Хотите разместить форму в клиентской области на всю ширину - просто назначайте ей parent, и уже без всяких MDI. По второму - и не даст, пока `align` не измените.